# Multilingual site in asp.net core 5 razor pages generate error for register page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to asp.net core Razor page and today i wanted to test multilingual site structure. Based on my experience i wanted to have separate files for English & Arabic version of website as design for both vary on some page so it it best option for me rather than using single page for both English & Arabic with help of localization etc.

I am not sure at this point to use common Identity pages for both languages or separate pages, as i am very new to asp.net core.

My folder structure test site is as below

[image]

General test page for english & arabic are accessible based on above structure & minor tweeks

```
English
https://localhost:44322/en/
https://localhost:44322/en/Privacy

Arabic
https://localhost:44322/ar/
https://localhost:44322/en/Privacy
```

### English Page

[image]

### Arabic Page

[image]

---

I am facing problem with Register page  `https://localhost:44322/Identity/Account/Register` as it generate error when i click on register link

I  changed path in `_ViewStart.cshtml` page under `Area/Identity/Account/Register`

```
@{
    Layout = "/Pages/en/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Path was changes to

- Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
- Layout = "/Pages/en/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
- Layout = "../Pages/en/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
- Layout = "Pages/en/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

For all above path mention in file it still generate error. I am not sure how i shoudl mention path for this scenario to make this page at least work.

Comment: Separate file for each culture is not a good choice! you should [read more about localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in the docs.

Comment: @LazZiya i agree with you, problem is that some page in Arabic are different in design than in English so using the Single file is challenging when design is different. I read your xLocalizer article and tested it It good You are really good at this me being an average or a part pr part time programmer make things bit difficult for me as at my job i have to do lot of stuff outside or programming.. I will read article mentioned by you also and stick to best practice..

Comment: if the design problem is only for layout direction, you can use solve this problem with [bootstrap 4 rtl](https://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/), just load the [relevant css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022815/how-to-enable-rtl-mode-in-right-to-left-culture-localization-asp-net-core-2-2-ap/57023097#57023097) depending on the text direction. At the end it is up to you to decide the localization infrastructure, if you will go with [XLocalizer](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer) I ensure it will save you a lot of time and effort :)

Comment: @LazZiya, Its not related to rtl that easy with Bootstrap by including relevant css, Its also the layout of page also which is different than English version in on some pages. as site grows i am being asked to add so things differently for one or the other version in some cases but not all. for this reason i switched to separate files for each language in webforms. if it was an web app then things are pretty straight forward but in terms of website design it is very challenging at times. I agree with you on XLocallizer.