# .Net Core Localization problem with Right to Left language

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, right-to-left

I am trying to put parametrized arabic string in resource file in a .net core project but when there is a placeholder at the end of the string it is moved at the beginning of the string.
When string is of this format

> الملف الشخصي {0} غير مناسب للوظيفة {1}

{1} is moved at the start of the string

String.Format is also changing the structure of the sentence

> قيد الجرعة بالاسم {0} موجود بالفعل

is converted into

> "قيد الجرعة بالاسم Test موجود بالفعل

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display direction in vs editor is not important, just make sure to set the html page direction to RTL. [See this answer for how to support RTL languages in a web page.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023097/5519026).

Back to your issue, you can switch the text direction while editing in the editor using right Ctrl+Shift buttons, but this will take effect only in the editor window.